# Xcode 9.1 - playgrounds broken

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-playground, xcode9.1

I am having absurd problems since updating to Xcode 9.1.

Opening playgrounds from the 'App Development with Swift' curriculum yields completely broken results, as you can see in the following image.

[as you can see there is no functioning button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw6ma.png)

Also, when I create a new empty playground (iOS, empty), I get greeted by the usual "Import UIKit" line but then the compiler tells me "UIKit no such module exists".

[UIKit no such module exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX1vU.png)

Could anyone shed some light on all of this?
I run Xcode 9.1 on a 2016 15" MacBook Pro, with macOS 10.12.6.

Thanks

UPDATE: downloaded Xcode v 9.0 and v 8.3.2. 9.0 doesn't have the issue with the playgrounds and 8.3.2 doesn't have the issue with the TouchBar.

Comment: What do you need the `UIKit` for in a playground? Just put `import Foundation` instead.

Comment: I didn't do it myself.  The playground created itself with it inside. I suppose that is an error? But why change it? Do you know also why the first mistake would happen? The one that makes disappear the navigation?

Comment: I did indeed cancel it out and inserted 'import Foundation'

Comment: By the way, how did you create the greyed out background for UIKit and import Foundation? I tried to look for instructions into the formatting section but didn't find anything ...

Comment: What do you mean by greyed-out background?

Comment: If you look at your first comment, the UIKit and import Foundation have a grey background. It seems something due to the markdown formatting but have no idea how to do so.  But please, could you (or anyone else) help me with this Xcode 9.1? It is so broken ...

Comment: Ohh I see. Just put backticks: `. You can also click *help* below *comment* to see formatting tips :)

Comment: `like this`? :) very tricky with Italian keyboard :)

Comment: Can confirm this. No workaround yet.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Mine's just fine ; There's some problem in you tools

Comment: Confirm same problem, except Xcode doesn't inform me of what's broken either. None of the suggested imports fix the problem. Reccomend different version of Xcode or online playground.

Comment: @jMan how can you make playgrounds online? Very interested in that! At the moment I have 9.2, 9.0 & 8.3.2 installed at the same time. Depending on what I need I use different versions

Comment: Beware of link-rot: https://iswift.org/playground... My current best workaround is `new project` -> `command line tool` and tinkering with the `main.swift`, breakpointing with the variables view if i need to stop it halfway.